# https что будет с сайтами, если сертификаты станут недоступны?

Tags: ssl, https

Вопрос по безопасности понятен. Банки и прочие организации понятно. Защита трафика это все понятно. Сертификаты стали доступны бесплатные. прям рай какой то...

Но... может специалисты прокомментировать, слова Игоря Ашманова. Правда, что если отключат корневые сертификаты, то сайты будут недоступны?
Дублируются ли куда то эти сертификаты? или это все байки

Хочется просто знать сам факт, кто хранит сертификаты и что будет если сертификаты станут недоступны?

Comment: Ну вообще информация о доверенных корневых сертификатах зашита прямо в браузеры/хранилища в ОС. Ее могло бы быть достаточно. Но есть например списки отзыва, которые браузер то же должен бы проверять. И они да, доступны только через ресурсы центров сертификации по сети

Comment: Не слушайте Ашманова. По этому вопросу и вообще. А по теме, Mike выше написал почему.

Comment: Тоесть их могут отозвать? И браузер тогда их удаляет. А почему не слушать? Вроде умный мужик